# PySpark Glue Error: Remote RPC Client Disassociated

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a PySpark code running in Glue which fails with error "Remote TPC Client Disassociated.Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues". It seems like it's a common issue with Spark and I have gone through a bunch of stack overflow and other forums. I tried tweaking a number of parameters in the Spark config but nothing worked hence posting this here. Would appreciate any inputs. Below are few details about my job, I have played with different values of the spark config for rpc and memory. I tried executor memory of 1g, 20g, 30g, 64g; Driver memory of 20g, 30g, 64g. Please advise.

Glue version: 3.0
Spark versio: 3.1

Spark Config:

```
spark= (SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("jkTestApp")
    .config("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
    .config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold","-1")
    .config("spark.rpc.message.maxSize", "512")
    .config("spark.driver.memory","64g")
    .config("spark.executor.memory","1g")
    .config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead","512")
    .config("spark.rpc.numRetries","10")
    .getOrCreate()
     )
```

Comment: Him Jatin, I have the same problem. Were you able to find a solution for this?